# Limit user form submission

Tags: php, forms, limit, submission

I'm using a simple form to send out some data. A user have to login to access the form (I have a database with users and passwords).

What I would like to do is to limit the number of times a user has successfully submitted the form and that is based on a response like this: mysite.com/send.php?code=0 (where only 0 means success and other values will be for an error).

I could manually add this limit in the database but I really don't know how to get around this.

Comment: So, you want to prevent a user who is logged in from submitting a form more than one time?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But it has to limit 1 successful submission (mysite.com/send.php?code=0 = succes / mysite.com/send.php?code=1 = error).

Comment: I don't understand the URLs you're including, but if you want to prevent multiple successful form submissions you will need to add a new column to the table related to this form so that you can track whether the form has been submitted by a given user.

Comment: I want to limit how many times a user sends the data over the form. But if the form gives an error (like the error URL above), the form shouldn't be considered sent.

I know I would have to add a new column but I don't know how to implement this to actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you might approach the desired feature. Without knowing exactly what parts of the feature you're having problems with, this is the best I can do. Please ask questions if something is not clear.

HTML form

```
<form method="post" action="myUrl">
    <input name="myField"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP to process the form

```
if(isset($_POST["myField"])){
    if(userHasNotSubmittedForm($_SESSION["userIdOrSomething"])){
        //update the column here with a database query
    }
    else{
        //tell the user they have already submitted this form.
        //Ideally, the user shouldn't be able to see this page
        //if they have already submitted this form, but this
        //behavior matches what you asked for.
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I get:


    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in sms.php on line 2 (line 2 being if(isset(POST["frm"])){

Comment: So, it looks like I forgot the `$_` in two places. I've added those now, but there's no possible way this code snippet is just going to work in your site. This is a blueprint of what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can get somewhere with your suggestion.